# MiniO docker container does not show files from local folder

Tags: docker, minio

I am trying to create a default bucket in MiniO docker container with my local files uploaded as a default content.

I have written a simple docker-compose file to run Minio client:

```
version: "2.0"
services:
  minio:
    image: 'bitnami/minio:latest'
    ports:
      - '9000:9000'
      - '9001:9001'
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: user
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - ~/test_data:/data
```

Inside the local folder `test_data`, there is a folder named `test_bucket` that contains 1 text file: `question_list.txt`

When I login to MiniO console in `localhost:9001`, I managed to see a default bucket created named `test_bucket`, but it is empty.

To double-check if the volume is mounted correctly, I looked inside the container with `docker exec -it test-minio-1 /bin/bash` and I could find the `question_list.txt` inside `/data/test_bucket/`.

I don't know why the `question_list.txt` is not showing up in MiniO console. I have tried to contact the developers in [GitHub](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-minio/issues/65) and it seems this is not possible.

I would like to ask if anyone faces similar issues and has a workaround, as for my actual use case, I will have GBs of local files that need to be used as default content inside the default bucket.

Thank you in advance for your constructive feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would like to update my situation.

My issue is mainly caused by the new feature from minio that applies versioning with metadata, as explained in [their blog post](https://blog.min.io/minio-versioning-metadata-deep-dive/). As it turns out, developers who used the older version of MinIO still could work normally as posted in this [forum](https://github.com/minio/minio/discussions/15238).

So to solve my current issue, I copy pasted the old config files stored in the folder `.minio.sys` from the old version of MinIO and now I can see the files appearing correctly in both my machine and the browser. I think that rolling back an older Docker image of MinIO would also solve my current issue.

As this is more relevant to my issue at hand, I will use this as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with extra service like this config:

```
version: "2"
services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./test/.minio/data:/export
      - ./test/.minio/config:/root/.minio
    environment:
      - "MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE"
      - "MINIO_SECRET_KEY=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY"
    command: server /export

  createbuckets:
    image: minio/mc
    depends_on:
      - minio
    volumes:
      - ./my-data:/tmp/data
    entrypoint: >
      /bin/sh -c "
      /usr/bin/mc config host add myminio http://minio:9000 AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY;
      /usr/bin/mc rm -r --force myminio/somebucketname;
      /usr/bin/mc mb myminio/somebucketname;
      /usr/bin/mc policy download myminio/somebucketname;
      /usr/bin/mc cp /tmp/data myminio/somebucketname;
      exit 0;
      "
```

Inspired by this Github issue: https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/4769#issuecomment-320319655

Comment: hi mostafa8026, thanks for the reply, this solution works, although unfortunately that means I have to use `minio/minio` and `minio/mc` rather than the original `bitnami/minio` docker that I originally intended.

Comment: I think you can change the charts so you can use helm charts in this way, but I have no idea how to implement that at the moment.

Comment: thanks for the additional comments, but that means there is still no possible solutions using `bitnami/minio`